# Link a high volume of pages using Facebook On Behalf Of Flow

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-business-manager

We have a large volume (400)+ pages to add via the [On Behalf Of](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/business-manager/guides/on-behalf-of/) flow. We are getting rate limited on [Step 4](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/business-manager/guides/on-behalf-of#step4) which installs our app in our client's business manager as a Connected App.

Is there an alternate approach to grant the system user created as part of this flow access to a large number of pages all at once rather than one page at a time? Meta Business Manager had this concept for the Parters but not Connected Apps.